# Can I use ":hover" effect to affect html tag CSS which is higher in the nesting hierarchy?

Tags: css, hover

Can I use ":hover" effect to affect html tag which is higher in the nesting hierarchy?
I am trying to affect element's CSS property by hovering over element lover in the hierarchy. As in example below.
HTML example

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS example
/* Usualy this is how we use it */

```
ul>li{
   color:red;
}
```

/* How can I use it other way round? */

```
li>div{
   color:blue;
}
```

/* or ? */

```
li>ul{
   color:yellow;
}
```

/* or ? */

```
a>div{
   color:black;
}
```

Examples most welcome.
Thank you very much guys.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do. 

li>ul, for example, means you reach a UL which is child of a LI .What of these elements are you trying to change state?

Comment: see this may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: there's no parent selector

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't. You can use javascript to do such a thing though.

Comment: I am trying to affect elements CSS property by hovering over element lover in the hierarchy. As in example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the best (and possibly only) way to do this is with the use of jQuery.

```
jQuery("a").parent("div').addClass('class_name');
```

then you can define the style using the class instead. To remove the class:

```
jQuery("a").parent("div').removeClass('class_name');
```

Comment: instead of adding a class can you also add CSS property ?

Comment: I would think it would be easier to maintain the code if you use a class. But then again, I suppose that's personal preference more than anything. Just seems that semantically, it would make more sense to assign a class of "hover" and then it would be clear in the CSS along with the rest of the styling.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in CSS4. But it is not supported in any of the major browsers.

You may find your answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)**

Comment: Not even in CSS4. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector#comment23407732_1014958

Comment: Is that answer equals to == "There is no way to do that in CSS that will work properly in most browsers ?" Is that right ?

Comment: Yes, that's the bottom line